# Flushright not working on images

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I found it hard to align small minipage on the right margin on top of an image by adjusting vspace (-5cm). There's a blank spot on the lower right corner of the image that I need to place a block of text on it. The block of text comes on the spot but slightly off the margin (about 18pt). How can I make it aligned with the rest of the document? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{  c  }
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.94\linewidth]{images/Fig-10} \\
\centering \textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[2]}\\ 

    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \vspace{-7cm}
    \begin{flushright}
     \begin{tabular}{  c  }
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}

\lipsum[11]

    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
       \end{flushright}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Can you try and explain it better?

Comment: A justified text block on the right margin of the page which is also on top of a full width image (100% textwidth). The result in my code is slightly off the right margin. I don't know why. Even using raggedleft doesn't work. Even using \hfill doesn't work. Even using ( \textbox{minipage =5cm, right ) doesn't work. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

- Sorry, but it's unclear what you after: two successive floats:

  - first with centered images and text below it
  - second with text in minipage shifted to the right
- If this is a case, than the following simple code should help you:

**Edit:**
From your comment below can be concluded, that like to obtain the following:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

One way to get this is to use nodes defined in the `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics[width=0.94\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}; %{images/Fig-10}
  \node[text width=0.4\textwidth, 
        align=justify,
        below left=0pt] at (image.north east)
                {\lipsum[66]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for showing the frames. It's the same what you did, except I want the small block of text to be on top of the image rather than at the bottom as shown in your image. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know how to add images here. There are only textareas. I don't see a way to put an image on this website.

Comment: @DhirghamMurran, now is a bit more clear, but it seems, that you will still need some fine tuning. See edited answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without tikz? I don't have tikz package.

Comment: @DhirghamMurran, if you not have installed `tikz`, that do this! This is very powerful, useful  and popular package. As you see. using it, solution is simple, clear and easy to understand.